# How to check that entered string contains Unicode: 0x1a value

Tags: java, unicode

I want to know that entered string is contains Unicode:0x1a value or not in java. I am not able to identify the value of → and other special character.

Comment: 0x1a is a byte, not a character. Interpreted as Ascii or UTF-8 data, it is a control code (“control character”). Interpreted as UTF-16 data (the internal encoding used in Java), it is just a byte of a two-byte representation of something. It is impossible to say what you are asking.

Answer (score 6):

Because the character "→" has a Unicode code point `\u2192`.

```
String s = "this is → my arrow";
if (s.contains("→")) {
  System.out.println("Contains arrow!");
} else {
  System.out.println("No arrows in my string :(");
}
```

As an alternative you may write the character in hex notation:

```
String s = "this is → my arrow";
if (s.contains("\u2192")) {
  System.out.println("Contains arrow!");
} else {
  System.out.println("No arrows in my string :(");
}
```

Comment: Hi vz, \u2192 is not working because there is junk character like arrow and there are multiple special character so I want to check all this kind of junk character

Comment: @Piyush Then it is unclear to me what your problem is. Please clarify your question and I'd be glad to help :)