# Check if java string contains unicode character

Tags: java, string, unicode

I'm trying to check to see if a string contains a specific unicode point from the Segoe MDL2 Assets font.

An example of a unicode value that I want to check for is

```
\uF14B
```

Here's where I'm grabbing my values from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font

How exactly can I check a string to see if it contains one of these values?

I have tried

```
        if (buttons[i].getText().contains("\uF14B")) {

            buttons[i].setFont(new Font("Segoe MDL2 Assets", Font.PLAIN, 15 )); 
        }
```

While this does work, I think that it's pretty ineffecient to have to copy and paste each and every value that I plan to use into a if statement.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Edit:

I ended up placing a ~ after each special character in my array, and parsed it like this. Are there any issues in doing this?

```
/** Creating the names of the buttons. */
String [] buttonNames = {

        "Lsh", "Rsh", "Or", "Xor", "Not","And",
        "\uE752~", "Mod", "CE", "C", "\uF149~", "\uE94A~",
        "A", "B", "\uF14D~", "\uF14E~", "\uE94F~", "\uE947~",
        "C", "D", "\uF14A~", "\uF14B~", "\uF14C~", "\uE949~",
        "E", "F", "\uF14A~", "\uF14B~", "\uF14C~", "\uE948~",
        "(", ")", "\uE94D~", "0", ".", "\uE94E~" 
        };

/** more code here */

if (buttons[i].getText().contains("~")) {

                buttons[i].setFont(new Font("Segoe MDL2 Assets", Font.PLAIN, 15 )); 
                buttons[i].setText(buttons[i].getText().substring(0, buttons[i].getText().lastIndexOf('~')));
            }
```

Comment: What I mean is, how exactly can I check to see if my string contains a unicode value. For example, checking if a string contained \u (although I know this actually won't work.)

Comment: you can use `Matcher`s for this.

Comment: Every (non-empty) string contains unicode characters.

Comment: Possible Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109928/6785649

Comment: An `F1xx` series character is not a font or even a "character" really, in that it doesn't have an assigned glyph or meaning.  Basically "private use" is exactly that, and anyone can use it for anything.  I think some websites use the same code points for random graphical glyphs like lines, elbows and arrows to help draw their UI.

Comment: Might have found a solution that I can easily understand.

Comment: *"I ended up placing a ~ after each special character in my array"* What array? And if you place `~` characters in your button text, won't the buttons look weird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invert the font selection logic:

The `Font` class has goodies like `canDisplay` and [canDisplayUpTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-). Javadoc:

```
public int canDisplayUpTo​(String str)
```

> Indicates whether or not this Font can display a specified String. For
>   strings with Unicode encoding, it is important to know if a particular
>   font can display the string. This method returns an offset into the
>   String str which is the first character this Font cannot display
>   without using the missing glyph code. If the Font can display all
>   characters, -1 is returned.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I wouldn't have found this without your help. You saved me ~50 lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

The best / easiest way to scan text to find certain characters is to use a regular expression character class.

A character class is written as `[xxx]` where `xxx` can be set of single characters, e.g. `a` or `\uF14B`, and/or ranges, e.g. `a-z` or `\uE700-\uE71F`.

So, you can write a regex like this:

```
[\uE700-\uE72E\uE730\uE731\uE734\uE735\uE737-\uE756]
```

and so on *(that was about 10% of the code points list on the [linked page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font))*.

The above can also be done using exclusion, i.e.

```
[\uE700-\uE756&&[^\uE72F\uE732\uE733\uE736]]
```

where the `[^xxx]` means "not any of these characters".

You then compile it and use it to check strings:

```
String regex = "[\uE700-\uE72E\uE730\uE731\uE734\uE735\uE737-\uE756]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

if (p.matcher(buttons[i].getText()).find()) {
```

Comment: I came up with a way to do it myself, can you check to see that this is an okay way of doing this?